# sonarqube install fail on Windows + PostgreSQL

Tags: windows, postgresql, sonarqube

I create a user `sonarqube` on Postgres.

I create a database `sonarqube` on Postgres.

I add `host    sonarqube    sonarqube    127.0.0.1/32    md5` in pg_hba.conf

I custom sonar.properties file:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.password=sonarqube

sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube
```

When I start Sonar (sonarqube-6.5\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat) I have this logs:

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2017.09.11 11:49:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-6.5\temp
jvm 1    | 2017.09.11 11:49:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-6.5\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\sonarqube-6.5\temp\sq-process7757413999425394311properties
jvm 1    | 2017.09.11 11:49:44 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2017.09.11 11:49:44 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-6.5\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;C:\sonarqube-6.5\lib\jdbc\postgresql\postgresql-42.1.1.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\sonarqube-6.5\temp\sq-process301306345978378097properties
jvm 1    | 2017.09.11 11:49:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2017.09.11 11:49:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2017.09.11 11:49:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Check `logs/web.log`. The real error is likely there.

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: le rôle « sonarqube » n'est pas autorisé à se connecter (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs  => I see my postegres conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve when I change privilege of sonarqube role in my PostgreSQL data base:

[image]